# Detect Key Input from specified Keyboard C# (2 Keyboards)

Tags: c#, input, keyboard

For Example: 2 have 2 keyboards (one is called Keyboard-1 and Keyboard-2) And if i press D on Keyboard-1 it should do nothing but if i press D on Keyboard-2 it should give an output

```
if(e.KeyDown = Key.D && Keyboard-2){
  Console.WriteLine("D on Keyboard-2 got pressed");
  //Code etc...
}
```

Comment: Your question needs more information to be answered.  Is it a console app, a WinForms app, WPF, maybe something running in a browser.  In the code you show, what is `e`, is it a `KeyEventArgs` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs)?  What type is your `Keyboard` variable, and why are you subtracting `2` from it?  Whatever it is, I know of no type where an expression like `Keyboard-2` would yield a `bool` (which is required for `&&`)

Comment: I have no idea how authoritative this is (or whether it's changed since 2015), but this might help: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard